# Detect object touching or blocking front sensors on iPhone—without using camera

Tags: ios, iphone, arkit

I’m looking to detect when an object is blocking the front sensor region on an iPhone. I have identified a potential solution that uses the front-facing camera to determine overall average luminance (light/darkness) of the camera view as a proxy for detecting when something is blocking the sensor region, but my use case requires avoiding use of the camera.

I’ve tried using the proximity sensor (proximityState), but whenever proximity monitoring is active, the screen automatically turns off. This won’t work for my use case, unfortunately.

I have also discovered the means of accessing the ambient light sensor (ambientLightSensor), but it appears to be restricted for approved research study applications only.

Are there other public iOS APIs that use sensors or capabilities I am not aware of, such as ARKit, or something else that could fit the bill here? Trying to avoid it as much as we can but will we need to fall back to using the camera.